# Double hop SQL delegation not working

Tags: .net, sql, delegation

I've been trying to diagnose this for some time, and unfortunately Im still getting the dreaded anonymous logon issue when trying to connect to a sql db as a domain user.

Steps taken:

- App Pool created with delegation service acct
- Site / Virtual dir running with Integrated Windows auth only
- Made sure site itself can use kerberos KB 215383
- Service acct added to IIS_WPG group
- Service acct added to "act as part of operating system" under Local
  Security settings
- Service acct added to Log on as service under Local Security Settings
- HTTP SPN set for web address + service account (and FQDN)
- MSSQLSvc SPN set for sql box and domain acct sql is running as
- Trust for delegation turned on service acct, specified services, and
  sql service acct

After all this, Im still getting the exact same error from when I started. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. This has advanced my balding by at least 5 years so far. I would greatly appreciate any additional tips on diagnosing or setting up.

Comment: I suggest you flag this question and request to be migrated to ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out using setspn -L found some conflicts with a service acct. Using setspn -D to get rid of those conflicts fixed the issue.

First time doing this, Kerberos is very picky! And as always, thank you SO Community

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NTLM authentication, double hop won't work. You may have to install Kerberos.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx